# Build a string in Bash with newlines

Tags: bash, shell, newline

I'm going through a script in Bash where, depending on the conditionals, I want to append to a variable different things and then display it at the very end. Something like this:

```
VAR="The "

if [[ whatever ]]; then
    VAR="$VAR cat wears a mask"
elif [[ whatevs ]]; then
    VAR="$VAR rat has a flask"
fi
```

But I run into difficulties if I try to use this form of building up *VAR* by appending to it when I want to occasionally append newlines into it. How would I do `VAR="$VAR\nin a box"`, for example?

I have seen usage of `$'\n'` before, but not when also trying to use `$VAR` because of the appending.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
var="$var"$'\n'"in a box"
```

You could put the `$'\n'` in a variable:

```
newline=$'\n'
var="$var${newline}in a box"
```

By the way, in this case, it's better to use the concatenation operator:

```
var+="${newline}in a box"
```

If you don't like ANSI C quoting, you can use `printf` with its `-v` option:

```
printf -v var '%s\n%s' "$var" "in a box"
```

Then, to print the content of the variable `var`, don't forget quotes!

```
echo "$var"
```

or, better yet,

```
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

**Remark.** Don't use upper case variable names in Bash. It's terrible, and one day it will clash with an already existing variable!

---

You could also make a function to append a newline and a string to a variable using indirect expansion (have a look in the [*Shell Parameter Expansion* section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)) as so:

```
append_with_newline() { printf -v "$1" '%s\n%s' "${!1}" "$2"; }
```

Then:

```
$ var="The "
$ var+="cat wears a mask"
$ append_with_newline var "in a box"
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
The cat wears a mask
in a box
$ # There's no cheating. Look at the content of 'var':
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="The cat wears a mask
in a box"
```

---

Just for fun, here's a generalized version of the `append_with_newline` function that takes *n+1* arguments (*n≥1*) and that will concatenate them all (with exception of the first one being the name of a variable that will be expanded) using a newline as separator, and puts the answer in the variable, the name of which is given in the first argument:

```
concatenate_with_newlines() { local IFS=$'\n'; printf -v "$1" '%s\n%s' "${!1}" "${*:2}"; }
```

Look how well it works:

```
$ var="hello"
$ concatenate_with_newlines var "a gorilla" "a banana" "and foobar"
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
hello
a gorilla
a banana
and foobar
$ # :)
```

It's a funny trickery with `IFS` and `"$*"`.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Bash does not process escape characters. The assignment

```
VAR="foo\nbar"
```

assigns 8 characters to the variable `VAR`: 'f', 'o', 'o', '', 'n', 'b', 'a', and 'r'. The POSIX standard states that the `echo` command should treat the two-character string `\n` in its arguments as a linefeed; Bash does not follow the standard in this case and requires the `-e` option to enable this processing. The `printf` command follows the POSIX specification and treats literal "\n" in its argument as a linefeed, but does not expand such uses in strings that replace placeholders: `printf "%s\n" "$VAR"` would still output

```
foo\nbar
```

instead of

```
foo
bar
```

To include an actual linefeed character in a string, you can use ANSI quoting:

```
VAR=$'foo\nbar'
```

which has the drawback that the string is otherwise processed as a single-quoted string, and cannot contain parameter expansions or command substitutions. Another option is that a string that spans multiple lines will contain the quoted linefeed characters:

```
$ VAR="foo
> bar"
$ echo "$foo"
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

It works this way:

```
VAR=foo
VAR="$VAR\nrat has a flask"
echo -e "$VAR"

# or of you're using bash then use
printf "%b\n" "$VAR"
```

Output:

```
foo
rat has a flask
```

Comment: -e was the missing piece.  this is the only post that shows it.