# How can I do ANSI C quoting of an existing bash variable?

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912681/build-a-string-in-bash-with-newlines), but it does not cover my use case.

Suppose I have the variable `foo` which holds the four-character literal `\x60`.

I want to perform [ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) on the **contents** of this variable and store it into another variable `bar`.

I tried the following, but none of them achieved the desired effect.

```
bar=$'$foo'   
echo $bar     
bar=$"$foo"     
echo $bar
```

Output:

```
$foo
\x61
```

Desired output (actual value of `\x61`):

```
a
```

How might I achieve this in the general case, including non-printable characters? Note that in this case `a` was used just as an example to make it easier to test whether the method worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By far the simplest solution, if you are using `bash`:

```
printf %b "$foo"
```

Or, to save it in another variable name `bar`:

```
printf -v bar %b "$foo"
```

From `help printf`:

> In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1)
>      and printf(3), printf interprets:
>
> ```
>  %b        expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
>  %q        quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
>  %(fmt)T output the date-time string resulting from using FMT as a format
>          string for strftime(3)
> ```

There are edge cases, though:

> \c terminates output, backslashes in \', \", and \? are not removed,
>   and octal escapes beginning with \0 may contain up to four digits

Comment: To elaborate on how the edge cases differ from `$'...'` strings: `\cx` Control-x sequences that `$'...'` interprets won't work; what `$'...'` interprets as a *3*-digit octal sequence _followed by a literal digit_, this solution interprets as a _single, 4-digit_ escape sequence; e.g.: `\0102`, when  prefixed by `$`, is a Backspace character (octal `\010`) followed by literal `2`, whereas `printf %b` interprets it as literal `B` (code point `0102` is decimal `66` - the letter 'B').

Comment: @mklement0: you reminded me that I forgot to put the -v option into that command line. Fixed.

Comment: `printf -v` for _storing the output in a variable_ is indeed the right solution here; do NOT use _command substitution_ as follows: `bar=$(printf %b "$foo")` - command substitution will _invariably trim any trailing newlines_ from the output.

Comment: P.S.: [@n.m.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23235918/45375) is still the one that comes closest to the behavior of `$'...'`.

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
 eval bar=\$\'$x\'
```

The command bar=$'\x61' has to be constructed first, then eval evaluates the newly built command.

Comment: Good luck if your variable contains a string like `$(rm -rf /)`.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but agreed it is a little scary.

Comment: I'm used to writing portable shell scripts, so this came to mind first.   Using an 'eval' on user-tainted input without validation would not be good.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I can do this. Edited based on comments.

```
bar=$( echo -ne "$foo" )
```

Comment: This almost works except `\"` is not interpreted as a double quote character.

Comment: +1; `echo -e` is superior to `printf` in that `%` chars. needn't be escaped. There is an edge case, however: command substitution _trims trailing newlines_, so if your string _ends_ in one or more `\x0a` or `\n` sequences, they are discarded.

Comment: I suppose you can overcome the trailing newlines issue by appending a printable string to `$foo` and then trimming the output with `${var%pattern}` bash substitution.

Comment: Aside from the trailing-newlines issue, the same limitations as with @rici's `printf %b` solution apply: "\c terminates output, backslashes in \', \", and \? are not removed, and octal escapes beginning with \0 may contain up to four digits" (ANSI-C quoting only interprets up to *3* octal digits).

Comment: To avoid the trailing-newlines issue, you can combine `read` with _process substitution_ in lieu of the command substitution: `IFS= read -d '' -r bar < <(echo -ne "$foo")`

Answer (score 2):

The best method I know is

```
  y=$(printf $(echo "$foo"|sed 's/%/%%/g'))
```

As mentioned in the comments, this trims trailing newlines from `$foo`. To overcome this:

```
moo=$(echo "${foo}:end"|sed 's/%/%%/g')
moo=$(printf "$moo")
moo=${moo%:end}
# the escaped string is in $moo
echo "+++${moo}---"
```

Comment: +1, because this comes closest (deals with the `\"` issue), but there is an edge case: command substitution _trims trailing newlines_, so if your string _ends_ in one or more `\x0a` or `\n` sequences, they are discarded.

Comment: With the trailing-newlines issue dealt, this solution now _almost_ behaves the same as direct ANSI-C quoting: `\c{x}` sequences - e.g. `\ci` for Control-I, i.e., a `\t` char. - are not handled correctly; `\c` is treated as a literal sequence so that, e.g., `\ci` remains unmodified instead of expanding to a `\t` char.

Comment: @mklement0 `\c{x}` is not ANSI C.

Comment: I think it _is_ an ANSI-C quoting feature: from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting `"\cx    a control-x character"`. Try `printf $'\ci' | od -a` to see that it prints a tab.

Comment: @mklement0: `\cx` is certainly not part of "ANSI-C", which defines exactly the following escape sequences: `\' \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v`, octal escapes (up to 3 octal digits), hexadecimal escapes (`\x` followed by any number of hexadecimal digits), and universal character names (`\u` followed by four hex digits or `\U` followed by 8 hex digits). That's it. However, `bash` *also* interprets some non-ANSI-C escapes, including `\e` and `\cx` (but the latter only in some contexts; in other contexts `\c` terminates input), and fails to interpret ANSI-C standard `\?`.

Comment: @rici: Thanks for clarifying, but we are talking about a **bash feature** that _bash itself_ calls [**ANSI-C Quoting**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), **as implemented with `$'...'`** - in that _specific context_, `\cx` **is** interpreted as a control-x sequence. And that very context's behavior is what the OP desires.

Comment: An alternative to the append-a-string-then-remove-it approach to avoid the trailing-newlines issue is to use `printf -v`: `printf -v bar "$(sed 's/%/%%/g' <<<$foo)"` (thanks, @rici). (Note that in the original command substitution-based approach the inner `$(...)` should be double-quoted).

Comment: @mklement0 The bash manual correctly marks some of the escape sequences (`\e`) as being not ANSI C. Others that are also not ANSI C are not so marked (erroneously it would appear). The name of the feature is a misnomer, it should be properly called "C-style escape sequences".

Comment: n.m., @rici: Let's take stock: (a) **ANSI-C quoting** is an **established bash term** referring to the features supported in `$'...'` strings; (b) the features there are actually a _superset_ of what bona-fide ANSI C strings support, and 'ANSI-C quoting' is therefore a bit of misnomer - duly noted; (c) _this_ question is about the _bash_ feature, not ANSI C.

Answer (score 2):

Since bash 4.4 there is a variable expansion to do exactly that:

```
$ foo='\x61';     echo "$foo" "${foo@E}"
\x61 a
```

To set another variable use:

```
$ printf -v bar "${foo@E}";     echo "$bar"
a
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample of conversion via shell. Problem, the code is octal using `\0nnn` and hexdecimal (not on all shell) using `\xnn` (where `n` are [hexa]digit)

```
foo="\65"
print "$( echo "$foo" | sed 's/\\/&0/' )"

5
```

with awk, you could certainly convert it directly