# Append a multiline message in git hook

Tags: bash, git, sed

I am using `prepare-commit-message` hook to append a custom multi-line message to my commits. This message comes from a different source.

My hook file contents are like:

```
COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
COMMIT_SOURCE=$2
SHA1=$3

MESSAGE=$(some_command)

if [ -z ${2+x} ]; then
    sed -i.back "1s/^/$MESSAGE \n/" "$1"
fi
```

This works when the `MESSAGE` is a single line of text. But when it is multiline, I get

`unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`.

`echo $MESSAGE` would give me something like:

```
aaaa
bbbb
```

Basically, what I want to do is whenever I commit, the commit message should contain:

```
<here i will enter my commit message>

aaaa
bbbb
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
...
```

Comment: What happens when you replace `MESSAGE=$(some_command)` with `MESSAGE=aaa\nbbbb`? On my bash (v4.4.19) and sed (v4.4) two lines are inserted at the beginning of $1 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed is not needed there. You should be able to avoid all of these issues this way:

```
mv $1 $1.back
(echo $MESSAGE ; cat $1.back) > $1
```

Using sed, there appears to be no easy way to solve that problem without doing complicated ANSI-C quoting of the newlines inside $MESSAGE, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235651/how-can-i-do-ansi-c-quoting-of-an-existing-bash-variable) Stack Overflow post.